# Background code for long image in HTML doesn't produce expected results

Tags: html, css, background-image

I've tried css and html but both haven't produced the expected results. My background image is 2000px long and 810px wide.

HTML

```
<body>
<img src="http://i1162.photobucket.com/albums/q535/SachithPerera1/Fiverr%20-        %20Living%20Thin%20Philadelphia/bg_zpse26c2157.png" class="bgpic" />
</body>
```

CSS

```
 body
 {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 810px;
 height: 2500px;
 }

 .bgpic
 {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: Please add some code or fiddle so we can see in more detail what you have already tried and what is your issue.

Comment: What is y our expected result?  and what is it doing?

Comment: <body>
    <img src="http://i1162.photobucket.com/albums/q535/SachithPerera1/Fiverr%20-%20Living%20Thin%20Philadelphia/bg_zpse26c2157.png" class="bgpic" />
</body>

Comment: body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 810px;
    height: 2500px;
}

.bgpic
{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}

Comment: Image gets pixelated and stretched.

Comment: Add your code to your post rather than in the comments. This allows for better readability

Comment: Question lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.

Comment: show us what you have done

Comment: -1 changed to +1 for your edit

Comment: This is the URL: http://on.fb.me/MuUfs5

Comment: The image is actually only 435px wide.....hence the scaling issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to use `background-size:cover;` for this and tweak your CSS a bit. Something like the following should work well:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 810px;
  height: 2500px;
  background-image: url("image.url.here");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

After this, remove the `<img>` tag from your HTML and the `.bgpic` from your CSS and you'll be good to go!

`background-size:cover;` ensures that your image will always fill the area, in this case 810px by 2500px, and maintain it's aspect ratio.

Comment: Image still looks pixelated. May be the problem is with the image.

Comment: @SachithPerera Yes, if the image is pixelated, that means it is too low of a resolution to be displayed at that size.

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is a little off. You're not setting the body's background property; you're just placing an image the body of your page. You'll want to get rid of the `<img>` element and modify your body css to be something like this:

```
body { 
  background-image: url("http://i1162.photobucket.com/albums/q535/SachithPerera1/Fiverr%20-%20Living%20Thin%20Philadelphia/bg_zpse26c2157.png");
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the `background` property on your CSS to position background.

```
body {
    background: url("http://i1162.photobucket.com/albums/q535/SachithPerera1/Fiverr%20-%20Living%20Thin%20Philadelphia/bg_zpse26c2157.png") no-repeat top left; 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 810px;
    height: 2500px;
}
```

Comment: That does not spread the image over the entire area of 810 width and 2000 height

Comment: Then use the `background-size` attribute specified in CSS3. Check the MDN reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).